# With CTE: Getting error Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7 Incorrect syntax near ')'

Tags: sql-server-2008

This is my CTE:

```
with empcount(depid,totalemp)
as
(
    select depid, COUNT(*) as totalemp
    from emp
    group by depid
)
```

And I'm getting this error:

> Msg 102, Level 15, State 1, Line 7
>   Incorrect syntax near ')'.

Answer (score 2):

You have to use the CTE, for example with a `SELECT`:

```
WITH empcount(depid, totalemp) 
     AS (SELECT depid, 
                Count(*) AS totalemp 
         FROM   emp 
         GROUP  BY depid) 
SELECT * 
FROM   empcount
```

Answer (score 0):

I was experiencing the same issue, and guess what I was missing the following:

```
END TRY
BEGIN CATCH
END CATCH
```

Try block didn't end.  And that did it.
Thanks !